# Django cannot response json data

Tags: json, django, django-views

I create device function in views.py for return json data like this.

**views.py**

```
def device(request):
    
    responseData = {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Test Response',
        'roles' : ['Admin','User']
    }

    return JsonResponse(responseData)
```

I set url path to views.device() in urls.py like this.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('device/', views.device()),
]
```

when I save project it show error like this. How to fix it?

```
  File "C:\Users\MAX\Django\test_project\test\test\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('device/', views.device()),
TypeError: device() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your `device` function when your urls are loaded without the request.

Your urls just need to know what function to call.

Instead of having `path('device/', views.device()),` it should be `path('device/', views.device),`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#example